# Correlation Question - revised

Tags: correlation

[image]

Look at the correlation between Risk-Taking (R) and Relationship Happiness (HAPPY). Use the standard alpha level of 5%.  How would you describe the relationship?

A1: The relationship is non-significant.
A2: There is a significant negative relationship.
A3: There is a significant positive relationship.
A4: The correlation is zero.

The Sig = .053.  This is more than .05, so I accept the null, they are equal?  The scattergram that I ran shows straight lines.  Is this an indication that they are statistically significant and negative or positive?

Answer (score 0):

You never accept the null, you simply fail to reject it. (It's like finding a person "not guilty" rather than "innocent" in a criminal trial). But, since the p value is over 0.05, it isn't significant.  That should get you to the right answer. I don't know what lines you drew on a scatterplot.